# Unexpected physicsBody in SpriteKit scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm implementing a mass-spring system (many small physics bodies joined together with SKPhysicsJointSpring instances) with SpriteKit. Some of the particles would get snagged while traversing the center of the scene.

There seems to be a small, static body in the middle of the scene and I don't know why it's there.

Here's an easy way to see what I'm talking about:

1. In XCode 8, create a brand new project with the "Game" template.
2. In `GameViewController.viewDidLoad()`, add `view.showsPhysics = true`

If you run the project, you should see a little dot in the middle, which is the errant body:

[image]

Anyone know how to get rid of it?

**Edit:** I tried to manually create the scene object:

In `GameViewController.viewDidLoad()`, I replaced this:

```
// Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    view.presentScene(scene)
}
```

with this:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)
scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
view.presentScene(scene)
```

but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Anyways, I decided to make an answer because comments are not suitable due to lot of info I want to share. Also my answer, sadly, doesn't answer the question but it gives some useful info about this unidentified, obviously capable of flying (physics body) object :)

So this is the code how to grab it (and modify it???):

```
 //you can use self.frame here...I just copied Alessandro's code
 self.physicsWorld.enumerateBodies(in:(label?.frame)!) { body, stop in

    if let node = body.node {

        print("Type of this node: \(type(of:node))")    
        print("Frame of this node: \(node.frame))")

    }else{

       print("This body's node property is nil")

        body.affectedByGravity = true
        body.isDynamic = true

        body.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.003, dy: 0.0003))

    }
     print("Area covered by this node physicsBody: \(body.area)")
}
```

So if you put a break point inside of that else statement, you can scan this physics body completely and get all the info about it, like that its **node property is set to nil** or that its `isDynamic` property is  set to `false`. But you can change that, and like in my code, set for example `isDynamics` to true. This makes it moveable. So if you apply some forces to it, it will move.

Still, like I said in comments, I don't have an idea why it is there and what it represents or what is its purpose.

Also, for those who are wondering how it is possible that one physics body doesn't have a node associated with it ( `body.node` equals `nil`) but is still visible on screen when `showsPhysics` is set to `true`, there is a reasonable explanation. Physics world is separated from the node tree. So we can remove a sprite from a node tree, but that doesn't mean that its physics body will be removed instantly. It may happen that physics engine haven't finished simulation... So you probably wonder, how this might happen?

Let say you have three `SKSpriteNode` objects intersecting at the same time (say A contacts B and A contacts C at the same time). `SpriteKit` can process only one contact at time. And say that you are removing A from a parent when it is contacting with B. Then, there is a contact between A and C also, so `didBegin:(_ contact)` will be called twice. And if you remove A from its parent in first `didBegin(_ contact)` call, in the next `didBegin(_ contact)` call, `bodyA.node` will be nil (`bodyA` is a physics body of sprite A), but its physics body will remain visible until engine finishes what needed. This is because node tree and a physics world are separated.

Comment: Also as some additional info, I would add that this is a circular body ( with an, obviously very small area that equals to 0.000139626354211941) and it is present in both cases, like OP said - when you create a scene from a .sks file, or when creating it using other `SKScene` initializers. The only difference will be in its final position which depends of scene's anchor point which is 0.0, 0.0 by default (bottom left corner) or 0.5, 0.5 (middle of a screen) which is default `anchorPoint` for a scene when loaded from .sks file.

Comment: OK, got this to work, but I can't find a way to remove that physicsBody entirely.  Yes I can make it move, but changing it's categoryBitMask seems to have no effect, least of all making it 'invisible' to the bodies _I_ am adding.

Comment: So, setting the categoryBitMask isn't enough.  I needed to change the collisionBitMask as well.  This is pretty rubbish to have to do this.  I will file a radar.

Comment: I've filed a radar, and have uploaded a demonstration project to Github for this at: https://github.com/pkclsoft/TestMysteryPhysicsBody

Answer (score 2):

About the "**hello world**" xCode game template , it seems a little `physicsBody` associated to the `GameScene` node.
With some code I've found this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    private var spinnyNode : SKShapeNode?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        ... 
        // End part of this function:
        if let b = physicsWorld.body(in: (label?.frame)!) {
            if let node = b.node {
                print("Type of this node: \(type(of:node))")
                print("Frame of this node: \(node.frame))")
            }
            print("Area covered by this node physicsBody: \(b.area)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

With a breakpoint to the last brace, you can see **two bodies** (maybe an array of bodies), one of them is the `physicsBody` to the left **debugArea** (array with index **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBYud.png)**) with the same *hex address* as my body `b` in my code : **0x79794f90**, a little rectangle body with area 4.444

```
Printing description of ((PKPhysicsBody *)0x79794f90):
<SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{-375, -667}, {750, 1334}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}]
(lldb)
```

[image]

Comment: I suspected GameScene.sks as well, but no dice. (see updated question)

Comment: I think these bodies could be something that will be implement to show physics to the future "hello world" template, I don't know, but as can you see there are two bodies.

Comment: Thanks for helping diagnose this, but this doesn't really answer the question of why the bodies are there or how to remove them. This seems like a problem with SpriteKit itself and not with the XCode template.

Comment: You welcome, anyway seems you can't remove them.I agree with you.

Comment: @scribu You can "remove" it but the question is why it is there, what is its purpose. After some tests made by  Alessandro and me, it turned out that this body by default has its isDynamic property set to false. But you can grab it and change that :) And you can apply an impulse to it and see how it flies out of the screen lol :) I can post you the code which does that.

Comment: @scribu I suspect this little physics body is there to keep the physics system in an "awake" state. Audio/Sound management in SpriteKit, the voice synths in AVFoundation require these kinds of tricks to keep them awake and in memory. Probably because of Apple's aggressive memory and/or resources management on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I have a game with two sprite nodes joined together (SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint) moving around an SKEditor created scene.
As per my design, this node-pair would impact a third sprite node and be propelled smoothly away from the third sprite node, EXCEPT when the impact was in the center of the scene. For the  center of the scene impact, the node-pair would compress together while be propelled away from the third sprite node, presenting a poor graphical image.

After significant time debugging my code, I found this post. Kudos for the explanations and code. I can’t answer the “why” question but for the “particles would get snagged while traversing the center of the scene” question my suggested solution is to **clear the collisionBitMask** instead of moving the body.

BTW categoryBitMask is 0 when loaded.

```
        //moves the problem offscreen unless it hits another node
                    //body.affectedByGravity = true
                    //body.isDynamic = true
                    //body.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0.003, dy: 0.0003))
        //
        // collisionBitMask loads with 4294967295 = default value to collide with all categories
        //
                    body.collisionBitMask = 0
```